# Getting UserDefaults is not returning anything

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a problem with `UserDefaults`. I am using `UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey)` because I also have a `Share Extension`. This is my setup:

**extension UserDefaults:**

```
func setDataSourceArray(data: [Wishlist]?){
    set(try? PropertyListEncoder().encode(data), forKey: Keys.dataSourceKey)
    synchronize()
}

func getDataSourceArray() -> [Wishlist]? {
    if let data = self.value(forKey: Keys.dataSourceKey) as? Data {
        if let dataSourceArray =
            try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array < Wishlist > .self, from: data) as[Wishlist] {
                return dataSourceArray
            }
    }
    return nil
}
```

**Calling set:**

```
 // save dataSourceArray in UserDefaults
if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
    defaults.setIsLoggedIn(value: true)
    defaults.setDataSourceArray(data: dataArray as? [Wishlist])
    defaults.setDropOptions(dropOptions: self.dropOptions)
    defaults.synchronize()
} else {
    print("error Main")
}
```

`Setting` works perfectly fine. No error.

**Calling get:**

```
if let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: UserDefaults.Keys.groupKey) {
        print(defaults.isLoggedIn())
        if defaults.isLoggedIn(){
            if let data = defaults.getDataSourceArray(){
                
                defaults.synchronize()
                print(data[0].name)

            } else {
                print("Error getting dataSourceArray")
            }
        } else {
            print("yeet")
        }
        
    } else {
        print("error 1")
}
```

This always prints: "Error getting dataSourceArray".
I am stuck and have no idea what Im doing wrong here, so Im happy for every help!

***UPDATE:***

I noticed a weird behavior which I can not explain: when in **Calling set** I only call `defaults.setDataSourceArray(data: dataArray as? [Wishlist])` without setting `isLoggedIn` and `dropOptions` it works fine?! Can anyone explain that to me?

Comment: don't use `try?` use `try catch` block

Comment: @Sh_Khan do you have any idea whats going on here?

Comment: @Chris You're not listening to what Sh_Khan said. You are throwing away all knowledge of what went wrong and then wondering what went wrong. That's silly. Why do we get nil? Is it because an `if let` failed? If so which one? Or is it because decoding failed? If so what's the error? Write your code so that you _know_ the answer. Don't waste your time and ours _guessing_.

Comment: @matt fair point. The chatted with him and we actually couldnt get the syntax right for a `try catch` but I solved the problem now anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem.. Stupid beginners problem. When `setDropOptions`  inside `UserDefaults` I used the `key` from `dataSourceArray`. Fixed that and its working now. Thanks for everyone who tried to help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Your set is nil

```
 defaults.setDataSourceArray(data: dataArray as? [Wishlist])
```

as `dataArray as? [Wishlist]` will fail to `nil`

```
func getDataSourceArray() -> [Wishlist]? {
    if let data = self.value(forKey: Keys.dataSourceKey) as? Data {  
            do {  
                  let dataSourceArray =  try PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array < Wishlist > .self, from: data) as[Wishlist] 
                  return dataSourceArray
            }
            catch { 
               print(error) 
            }
    } 
    return nil
}
```

Comment: why ? And how can I fix that ? Force ?

Comment: Treating a forced downcast to '[Wishlist]' as optional will never produce 'nil'

Comment: adding parentheses silenced the warning

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217568/discussion-between-chris-and-sh-khan).

Comment: there is some other issue at the moment.. maybe you can still help me out here :)

Comment: check out the chat

Comment: just posted a question about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62941032/value-not-found-when-retrieving-from-userdefaults