# Value not found when retrieving from UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

This is the exact `error` I get:

> valueNotFound(Foundation.Data, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_PlistKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "wishData", intValue: nil), _PlistKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "image", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected Data value but found null instead.", underlyingError: nil))

**Details:**

I have two custom `strcuts` :

**`Wishlist`** :

```
struct Wishlist: Codable {
var name: String
var image: UIImage
var wishes: [Wish]
var color: UIColor
var textColor: UIColor
var index: Int

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name, image, wishData, color, textColor, index
}

init(name: String, image: UIImage, wishes: [Wish], color: UIColor, textColor: UIColor, index: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.image = image
    self.wishes = wishes
    self.color = color
    self.textColor = textColor
    self.index = index
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    wishes = try values.decode([Wish].self, forKey: .wishData)
    color = try values.decode(Color.self, forKey: .color).uiColor
    textColor = try values.decode(Color.self, forKey: .textColor).uiColor
    index = try values.decode(Int.self, forKey: .index)

    let data = try values.decode(Data.self, forKey: .image)
    guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
        throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .image, in: values, debugDescription: "Invalid image data")
    }
    self.image = image
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    try container.encode(wishes, forKey: .wishData)
    try container.encode(Color(uiColor: color), forKey: .color)
    try container.encode(Color(uiColor: textColor), forKey: .textColor)
    try container.encode(index, forKey: .index)
    try container.encode(image.pngData(), forKey: .image)
}
}
```

And **`Wish`**

```
struct Wish: Codable {
public var name: String
public var checkedStatus: Bool
public var link: String
public var price: String
public var note: String
public var image: UIImage

init(name: String, link: String, price: String, note: String, image: UIImage, checkedStatus: Bool) {
    self.name = name
    self.checkedStatus = checkedStatus
    self.link = link
    self.price = price
    self.note = note
    self.image = image
}

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name, checkedStatus, link, price, note, image
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    checkedStatus = try values.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .checkedStatus)
    link = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .link)
    price = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .price)
    note = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .note)

    let data = try values.decode(Data.self, forKey: .image)
    guard let image = UIImage(data: data) else {
        throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .image, in: values, debugDescription: "Invalid image data")
    }
    self.image = image
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    try container.encode(checkedStatus, forKey: .checkedStatus)
    try container.encode(link, forKey: .link)
    try container.encode(price, forKey: .price)
    try container.encode(note, forKey: .note)
    try container.encode(image.pngData(), forKey: .image)
}
}
```

`Setting` to `UserDefaults` works without any error but `getting` fires the `error above`:

```
func getDataSourceArray() -> [Wishlist]? {
    if let data = self.value(forKey: Keys.dataSourceKey) as? Data {
        do {
            _ = try PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array < Wishlist > .self, from: data) as [Wishlist]
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
        if let dataSourceArray =
            try? PropertyListDecoder().decode(Array < Wishlist > .self, from: data) as[Wishlist] {
                return dataSourceArray
            } 
    }
    return nil
}
```

I know this might be quite confusing so let me know if there is anything you need to know. Im stuck here and have no idea what the problem is..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Image data is nil

> "image", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected Data value but found null instead."

so alter code in `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {`

```
if let data = try? values.decodeIfPresent(Data.self, forKey: .image),let image = UIImage(data: data) {
     self.image = image
}
```

With

```
public var image: UIImage?
```

and in your custom init do

```
, image: UIImage? = nil
```

---

Also change

```
try container.encode(image.pngData(), forKey: .image)
```

to

```
if let img = image , let im = img.pngData() {
  try container.encode(im, forKey: .image)
}
```

Comment: but it sohuld be ok if it is nil. So I have to make it an optional ?

Comment: how exactly can I do that ? in which `init`?

Comment: still not working. In this line `try container.encode(image?.pngData(), forKey: .image)` I had to add the "?" to make it work with your suggestion

Comment: do you want to have access to the project? maybe that helps

Comment: `Value of optional type 'UIImage?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'pngData' of wrapped base type 'UIImage'` should I force it ?

Comment: at least a different error: 
`keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "image", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_PlistKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "wishData", intValue: nil), _PlistKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"image\", intValue: nil) (\"image\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: you may also use `try values.decodeIfPresent(Data.self,`

Comment: youre the man... Never couldve figured that out by myself. thanks! One more thing I dont quite get is why it prints "set" twcice but its working so :D

Comment: @Chris you could accept other answer there too =D check if you set the vc twice or call it twice by a mistake like in `viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217989/discussion-between-chris-and-sh-khan).